# Explicit frame break with beamer class

Tags: beamer, page-breaking

I am looking for a way to insert explicit frame breaks. I'd like to use the built-in frame title continuation feature. The only way I have found is to play with different values of the `allowframebreaks` option, but one doesn't really have much control of where the frame break is actually set.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by a "framebreak" it's not clear what that is. Beamer provides a frame environment. You want beamer to do something within that environment?

Comment: If the content does not fit onto one frame, `allowframebreaks` option instructs beamer to automatically break it between two or more frames while keeping the frametitle of the first frame (given as argument to `frame` environment) and appending a roman number or something like cont'd.

Comment: So you want to be able to simulate this but with an explicit frame break?  Is that it?  Sort of like `\newpage` in articles.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use `\framebreak` to insert an explicit frame break (see the `beamer` manual p.61). Note that the manual warns on several different places to not use this feature because it is "evil".
The `\framebreak` macro stands for `\pagebreak<presentation>` and inserts the frame/page break only in presentation mode but e.g. not in article or other modes. Use `\pagebreak` directly if you don't want that.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\ A\\
\framebreak
B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\\framebreak B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\ B\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Command `\framebreak` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: why is this considered evil?

Comment: @Seamus: I was just citing the manual. Here the paragraph in full: p.61 "The use of this option is evil. In a (good) presentation you prepare each slide carefully and think
twice before putting something on a certain slide rather than on some different slide. Using the
allowframebreaks option invites the creation of horrible, endless presentations that resemble more a
“paper projected on the wall” than a presentation. Nevertheless, the option does have its uses. Most
noticeably, it can be convenient for automatically splitting bibliographies or long equations."

Comment: I see. It is evil from a _presentation_ point of view, not because it does violence to the internal creation of the presentation or the like. Thanks!

Comment: I have found that `\vfill` did not work any more when following a `\framebreak` while it did in a frame by itself

Comment: @Bastian: Well, fills on boundaries like framebreaks are discarded automatically. Try writing `\vfill\vspace{0pt}` to add an empty vbox after the fill in order to protect it.