# Breaking table of contents between frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, page-breaking

I've got a rather long table of contents for my presentation in `beamer`, and it doesn't fit on one frame. I know I can provide a table of contents per section, or to manually break it between sections into a few frames using `\tableofcontents[sections={1-3}]` etc., but I was hoping there is a way for LaTeX/beamer to do it automatically for me.

So, in short:

> Is it possible to automatically break the table of contents in beamer between frames?

And of course, if yes, how would I go about it?

Comment: If your table of contents doesn't fit on one slide, your presentation has too many parts.

Comment: @Seamus: Normally I'd agree with you, but I do have a legitimate reason for this: my talk is very long (3 academic hours), and discusses a certain taxonomy of 15-20 concepts in no particular order. So I wanted to use the table of contents as a handy index/navigation as well in the electronic version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try the `allowframebreaks` option

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=<fraction>]
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

It is for stuff like ToC or references.

See also [Explicit frame break with beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13380/2975)

Comment: It works in my tests but doesn't look good. You will have to tweak it a little.

Comment: They are right to call it evil. The result is kind of a mess, even with a finite number of `<fraction>` parameter tweaks. But there doesn't seem any better way to do it, so I'll accept your answer.