# Splitting TOC into two columns on single frame in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am doing a presentation but my table of content is too long with short titles for a single slide.

I was wondering if there was a way such that the table of contents appears on two columns.

Related question for too long TOC:
[Breaking table of contents between frames in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13526/breaking-table-of-contents-between-frames-in-beamer)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Load (in the preamble) the [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
```

and then, in the body of your document:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}
```

Edit: With the toc appearing all through the beamer, before the first frame:

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
   \begin{multicols}{2}
     \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
   \end{multicols}
  \end{frame}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Since I almost asked another question related, in case anyone else wonders I have edited your answer for when the TOC appears at the beginning of other sections.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Is it possible to control the location of the break point from thefirstcolumn to the second? Thanks

Comment: @pluton: I think it's better if you open a new question, perhaps linking to this one for background.

Comment: for anyone who is also seeing this option for the first time, other subsections are hidden with `hideothersubsections`, with an `s`.

Comment: I see one problem: The first row first entry in ToC is below to second row first entry.