# Two-column beamer ToC with control over the breaking point

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, page-breaking, two-column

From [Splitting TOC into two columns on single frame in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24343/splitting-toc-into-two-columns-on-single-frame-in-beamer/24344#comment-52568), I'd like to know whether it is possible to control the position of the breaking point between column 1 and column 2?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Apparently, `\addtocontents` also works with the `beamer` class. Use `\newpage` (not `\clearpage`!) to force a column break.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{\contentsname}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}

\section{bla}
\begin{frame}{bla}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\section{blubb}
\begin{frame}{blubb}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\section{foo}
\begin{frame}{foo}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage}

\section{bar}
\begin{frame}{bar}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do have also a solution to this realted problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159078/two-column-beamer-toc-with-control-over-the-breaking-point-and-without-balancing

Answer (score 22):

An excellent solution has been posted here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136082/113639

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-3}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={4-5}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

As you can see, the break points are manual here (using the `sections=` parameter). Furthermore, this solution avoids all the vertical alignment problems of the other `multicols` solutions I have seen here so far, where the second column would often not start at the top.