# Badly aligned two column Beamer ToC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm trying to make a nice two column table of contents in beamer. There are a lot of questions about it, but I can't see that anyone really answers my problem.

Using the `multicol` environment, splitting the ToC is easy. However, the ToC is internally badly aligned, even thought the number of entries are even. I've added the code

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}
  {\vfill}
  {\vskip1.5em}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

to add some more space, which also emphasises the bad alignment.

The question [Beamer: Vertical alignment of multi-column ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109748/beamer-vertical-alignment-of-multi-column-toc) addresses the problem, but the solution is manual (providing which sections of the ToC that should be printed in which column). I believe it probably should be some way to fill the space needed in the first column such that the top of the two columns are balanced, but I have no idea how. Any ideas?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriflarge]{serif}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}{Innhold}{\hfill}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.1\textwidth}
    \column{.8\textwidth}
   \begin{multicols}{2}
      \centering
      \tableofcontents[currentsection, sectionstyle=show/shaded,
  %subsectionstyle=show/show/hide
  ]
   \end{multicols}
    \column{.1\textwidth}
\end{columns}
  \end{frame}
}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}
  {\vfill}
  {\vskip1.5em}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  {Innhold}{}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.1\textwidth}
    \column{.8\textwidth}
      \begin{multicols}{2}
        \tableofcontents
      \end{multicols}
    \column{.1\textwidth}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need `columns` and `multicols` at the same time?

Comment: Just to squeeze the ToC – got the code from a friend :p

Answer (score 1):

In `beamerbasetoc.sty`, there is the definition of `\beamer@tableofcontents`

> ```
> \def\beamer@tableofcontents[#1]{%
>   \def\beamer@toc@cs{show}%
>   \def\beamer@toc@os{show}%
>   \def\beamer@toc@css{show}%
>   \def\beamer@toc@oss{show}%
>   \def\beamer@toc@ooss{show}%
>   \def\beamer@toc@csss{show}%
>   \def\beamer@toc@osss{show}%
>   \def\beamer@toc@oosss{show}%
>   \def\beamer@toc@ooosss{show}%
>   \beamer@showpartnumber=\c@part%
>   \beamer@pausesectionsfalse%
>   \beamer@pausesubsectionsfalse%
>   \def\beamer@tocsections{<*>}%
>   \setkeys{beamertoc}{firstsection=1}%
>   \setkeys{beamertoc}{#1}%
>   \vspace*{-.5em}{\makeatletter%
>     \pause[0]%
>     \@input{\jobname.toc}%
>     \vfill}%
>   }
> ```

Somehow the `\vspace*{-.5em}` at the beginning pushes down the TOC. So just remove it.

---

I know it is kind of surprising. Just try it and you will see the result.

Roughly speaking, `multicols` makes the first line of every column at least `1em` tall, that is, it is of height `1em` or higher. Therefore when you say `\vspace*{-.5em}`, the negative space itself becomes the first line. So you may image that the first line has height `1em` and depth `-.5em`. It is indeed a positive space, and hence pushed the contents *down*.

P.S. Technically, `\vspace`s, the verticals spaces, are different from horizontal boxes and do not have heights and depths, they are spaces already.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriflarge]{serif}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}{Innhold}{\hfill}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.1\textwidth}
    \column{.8\textwidth}
   \begin{multicols}{2}
      \centering
      \tableofcontents[currentsection, sectionstyle=show/shaded,
  %subsectionstyle=show/show/hide
  ]
   \end{multicols}
    \column{.1\textwidth}
\end{columns}
  \end{frame}
}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@tableofcontents[#1]{%
  \def\beamer@toc@cs{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@os{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@css{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@oss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@ooss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@csss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@osss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@oosss{show}%
  \def\beamer@toc@ooosss{show}%
  \beamer@showpartnumber=\c@part%
  \beamer@pausesectionsfalse%
  \beamer@pausesubsectionsfalse%
  \def\beamer@tocsections{<*>}%
  \setkeys{beamertoc}{firstsection=1}%
  \setkeys{beamertoc}{#1}%
  %\vspace*{-.5em}
  {\makeatletter%
    \pause[0]%
    \@input{\jobname.toc}%
    \vfill}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  {Innhold}{}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.1\textwidth}
    \column{.8\textwidth}
      \begin{multicols}{2}
        \tableofcontents
      \end{multicols}
    \column{.1\textwidth}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}
\section{This is a section}
\begin{frame}
  {}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the negative `vspace` pushes the ToC *down*?

Comment: @Holene see my edit

Comment: I don't know why, but copying the code into my MWE, changing the `vspace` to 0 or removing the entire entry, and compiling doesn't change a thing for me...

Comment: @Holene I added a MWE. If it does not work, then it is me who should say I do not know why :)

Comment: Is this the kind of result you get? https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mop13b6zams7hu/Screenshot%202015-08-24%2019.02.16.png?dl=0 I have emphasised the alignment in Skim