# beamer: Change size of "square" itemize symbol in table of contents (TOC)

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

- I have a `beamer` presentation with more than 9 sections.
- I want to use the `square` symbol for the TOC.
- When I have numbers larger than 9 the square is too small.
- **How can I increase the size of *all* `square`?**

*I use a bigger font in my actual document and the effect is more severe than shown in the MWE below.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz} % for \foreach

\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\begin{document}

\section{Overview}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \frametitle{\contentsname}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109748/
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-6}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={7-12}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\foreach \x in {1,...,11}{
    \section{Section \x}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\insertsection}
        Test
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update after the answer

- This is for others with a similar problem.
- The `square` size is hardcoded as explained in the answer.
- The code can be found in the file `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty` on your system (as explained in a comment of the answer).
- I added the original code to better understand the code in the answer.

---

```
% (sub-)section in toc: square

\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{square}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=1.75ex%
  \llap{%
    \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{section number projected}%
    \vrule width2.25ex height1.85ex depth.4ex%
    \hskip-2.25ex%
    \hbox to2.25ex{\hfil\color{fg}\inserttocsectionnumber\hfil}}%
  \kern1.25ex\inserttocsection\par}
```

Comment: Shall all squares be bigger or only the ones >9? Should they be still a square?

Comment: @samcarter Good point. I clarified the question (all squares should be the same size). I am offline now for an hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the square is hard coded in the definition of the template, hoewever you can create your own template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{muhhh}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=1.75ex%
  \llap{%
    \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{section number projected}%
    \vrule width2.7ex height2.12ex depth.58ex%
    \hskip-2.7ex%
    \hbox to2.7ex{\hfil\color{fg}\inserttocsectionnumber\hfil}}%
  \kern1.5ex\inserttocsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[muhhh]


\begin{document}

\section{Overview}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \frametitle{\contentsname}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109748/
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-6}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={7-12}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\foreach \x in {1,...,11}{
    \section{Section \x}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\insertsection}
        Test
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So you don't know a standard command to influence the square definition?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner As I said, it's hard coded. You could use a smaller font and smaller paper size :)

Comment: Could you point out where in the beamer code the square definition is hard coded?

Comment: Its in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`