# Two-column beamer ToC with control over the breaking point and without balancing

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, multicol

I'm using the solution provided by lockstep in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26929/two-column-beamer-toc-with-control-over-the-breaking-point to spread the TOC over two columns. However, this gives some strange balancing problem which looks like this:

```
1.) Bla      4.) Blabla

2.) Blabla   

3.) bla      5.) Blabla
```

But I would like to have it like:

```
1.) Bla      4.) Blabla

2.) Blabla   5.) Blabla

3.) bla
```

Since lockstep's solution used the mutlicol package I tried to use the non-balancing enviroment `multicols*`. But this seems to fail. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136082/36296 is not what you are looking for, is it?

Comment: I am glad, that it helped. Shall I turn it into an answer or do you want to wait in case someone out there has an automatic solution to this problem?