# TOC, too long for fitting

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I've used next code in to my preamble to make my TOC, because I want that the `section` I will talk about is shown. But now is my TOC too large for one frame, how can I make it fit in one frame?

```
\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Inhoudsopgave - Sectie \thesection}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}
```

Comment: Look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24343/splitting-toc-into-two-columns-on-single-frame-in-beamer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a smaller font size, e.g.:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{...}
  \small
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

Other possibilities:

- Shorter titles to avoid titles that need more than one line.
- Simpler section structure
- ...