# Multicolumn in ToC in Beamer with Metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, multicol, themes, beamer-metropolis

I was trying to get a 2-column `tableofcontents` in Beamer. I found one solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24344/38244) which uses [`multicol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package. Normally this works fine; but when I use it with [Metropolis](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/themes/metropolis/doc/metropolistheme.pdf) theme, the two columns I get are not properly aligned. The first column starts little below to the second column.

Here's my working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, block=fill]{metropolis}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \section{1 Section}
    \section{2 Section}
    \section{3 Section}
    \section{4 Section}
    \section{5 Section}
    \section{6 Section} 
    \section{7 Section}
    \section{8 Section}

    \begin{frame}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{multicols}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and here's the screenshot (note the position of first rows):

[image]

How can I fix this alignment issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround: you could simply split the columns manually:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, block=fill]{metropolis}

%\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \section{1 Section}
    \section{2 Section}
    \section{3 Section}
    \section{4 Section}
    \section{5 Section}
    \section{6 Section} 
    \section{7 Section}
    \section{8 Section}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
                \tableofcontents[sections=1-4]
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
                \tableofcontents[sections=5-8]
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]