# How to split slide in Beamer table of contents page?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, columns

I created a standard table of contents page in Beamer

```
\AtBeginSubsection[] {
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame} }
```

I have a lot of sections and this leads to the contents being cut out.

How can I split the page in two (something like `minipage`) or in the worst case continue in the next slide ?

Comment: This question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109748/beamer-vertical-alignment-of-multi-column-toc/136082#136082 might help you

Comment: First, you can use the solution in the post linked by samcarter, since this way you can split the ToC even on multiple frames. Second, I think that if your ToC is longer than one page, it is not reasonable to put it there. People can't remember the outline of the talk/section if it's longer than 3-4 items.

Comment: An answer can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13526/breaking-table-of-contents-between-frames-in-beamer