# TOC AtBeginSection carried subsubsection from other slides

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I used the code

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
%\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
\end{frame}
}
```

from [How to explicitly split long TOC in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351518/how-to-explicitly-split-long-toc-in-beamer)

However, I have a

```
\section{1}
\subsection{1.1}
\subsubsection{1.1.1}
\subsubsection{1.1.2}
\subsection{1.2}
\subsubsection{1.2.1}
\subsubsection{1.2.2}
\section{2}
\section{3}
\section{4}
\section{5}
```

when I tried to compile the latex, the title of

```
\subsubsection{1.1.1}
\subsubsection{1.1.2}
\subsubsection{1.2.1}
\subsubsection{1.2.2}
```

showed up in the TOC of

```
\section{2}
\section{3}
\section{4}
\section{5}
```

Is there a fix for it?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show the current section, I would use `section={\thesection}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
%\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
\tableofcontents[sections={\thesection}]
\end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\section{1}
\subsection{1.1}
\subsubsection{1.1.1}
\subsubsection{1.1.2}
\subsection{1.2}
\subsubsection{1.2.1}
\subsubsection{1.2.2}
\section{2}
\section{3}
\section{4}
\section{5}

    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```