# Does there exist such a command like \newframe in beamer class

Tags: beamer

Does there exist such a command in beamer class ? which have a similar effect as the \newpage command in document class. Suppose it exist and called **\newframe**, when I already have a block of text, I only need to insert several \newframe to cut the text into several frames. so that I can get rid of the fussy repetition of \begin{frame} and \end{frame}.
like this :

```
\newframe
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex
ttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextte
xttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextt
exttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
\newframe
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttett
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
\newframe
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex
\newframe
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex
\newframe
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
\newframe
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `\framebreak`? [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13385](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13385/110998)

Comment: Note that   `[allowframebreaks]` make the slide breaks  automatically, so you only need a `\framebreak` in case you need a break before to fill completely the slide. But anyway this make really title numbered slides of the same frame, not different frames (significant difference if you want to change the title of the frames or use overlays, for instance).

Comment: Suggestion: for very simplistic beamer edition, consider use Rmarkdown. In your fake code, you need simply replace `\newframe` by `#`  (or `# Foo`,  in case that you want the "Foo" titles for the frames).